# API command not setting the model

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a weird case of an API command ignoring the model that is used to read the API parameters. Here is the command, and the model.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Debates(string tag, [FromUri]GetDebatesModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, model.Fields);
    }
```

Model:

```
public class GetDebatesModel 
{
    public GetDebatesModel()
    {
        Fields = "(default)";
    }

    public string Fields{ get; set; }
}
```

And here is the WebApiConfig that maps commands to this function:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "contentNestedControllers",
            routeTemplate: "content/{controller}/{tag}/{action}",
            defaults: new { }
        );
```

when I do /content/hashtag/%23MinimumWage/Debates, it just provides the expected default value of "(Default)". This means that it recognizes and instantiates the model.

when I do /content/hashtag/%23MinimumWage/Debates?fields=someRandomnessHere
it just provides the same result as if I never included the fields parameter in the first place.

Interestingly enough, the fields parameter works if I change the tag parameter to an int, but fails if it's a string. can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the %23 in the uri was the problem. removing that made the model function again.